# iOS Chrome gives wrong window height

Tags: jquery, ios, google-chrome, window, height

I'm currently working on a javascript application.

And I'm using the $(window).height() for some calculations. When I run the website in safari it works fine, but chrome does something strange.  $(window).height() only gives the height between the bottom of the screen and the bar at the top. If you scroll down you can see more of the page, but this is just blank.

Is there a way to include this little bit of height to $(window).height() without harming the rest of the site?

I'm running iOS 7 beta 4 with Chrome 28.0.1500.16 and jQuery version v1.10.2

(This is also happening on iOS 6)

Thanks

Comment: Be aware that the NDA on iOS 7 restrict us from talk about this version of iOS 7 on any other site then the official Apple Developers Forum.

Comment: I dont think this is directly related to iOS 7 because it is only happening in chrome and this also happens on iOS 6

Comment: Chrome use the native webView from the iOS SDK, which is different in iOS7 then in 6.

Comment: Yeah, but this is also happening on iOS 6

Answer (score 0):

The window is defined as the browser's "viewport". That is only the elements that are currently visible in the browser.  Everything off screen is not included in $(window).height().  Without seeing your page, it is possible that the two browsers have slightly different viewports, and Safari fits everything in the viewport and Chrome does not.

Use $(document).height() if you want the height of the entire page, including what is off-screen.